# Number of words of length L with a specific pattern

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Let an alphabet with $R$ letters. Let $A$ belongs to my alphabet. How many words of length $L>0$ can I build such that the pattern "$AAAA...A$" ($s>0$ times the letter $A$) appears at least 1 time? My idea was to detect the first time $1<k<L-s$ such that the pattern "$AAA...A$" appears in a word (meaning the $A$ at the left is at position $k$) but this leads to a recursive formula pretty hard to solve. Do you have an other idea ?

I noted $I_{L}$ the number of words of length $L$ such that  the pattern $AAAA...A$ appears at least 1 time.

We can notice that the number of words of length $L$ such that the pattern "$AAAA...A$" never appears is equal to $R^{L}-I_{L}$.

Comment: Easier to count the words that do not contain $A^s$, note that all of those must end in $XA^k$ where $X\neq A$ and $0≤k<s$ (must handle the words of length $<s$ separately, but that's easy).